# LSZ formula in spontaneously broken gauge symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory

The LSZ formula connects scattering amplitudes with the pole structure of correlation functions. I've only seen the derivation for $\phi^4$, and the poles where then simply the dressed propagators of the external legs.

But if a massive exchange boson would be involved, the pole structure would have to include a pole at the mass of this, right?
How does the LSZ formula look in a spontaneously broken gauge symmetry?

Comment: What do you mean "how does the LSZ formula look"? From the viewpoint of the effective theory, the formula doesn't look any different from that for a massive vector boson, since the effective theory *is* a theory of a massive vector boson. The general LSZ formula is rather cumbersome to derive and write down, but I am confident it is somewhere in Weinberg. Can you be more specific about what you want to know?